# Symfony2 file upload with ExtJS

Tags: extjs, file-upload, symfony

I want to handle file upload with Symfony2, but I'm using ExtJS (4.0).
Cookbook to handle upload with docrine doesn't work for me. It always fails when i check $form->isValid().
I have rad all "stacks" about handling forms with Symfony, and I don't know where to find my mistake, so...
I ask you for something different - handle file upload using pure PHP, and persist it to DB using only filename, but I want to bind my form data to Symfony's File type, to have access to methods to guess extension, and more.
Is there any way to achieve this?

UPDATE
Instead `$form->isValid()` which always returns **FALSE** for me, I used validator service:

```
$validator=$this->get('validator');
$errors=$validator->validate($file);
if(count($errors)){
...
}
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to retrieve some error code :

```
$uploadedFile = $form['the_form_widget_with_file_name']->getData();
$error_code = $uploadedFile->getError();
```

`$uploadedFile` will be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile .

Some explanation about the error code: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Something strange - callign `$form->isVaild()` always returns false. But when I use validator service instead, and validate Entity which persist files to the DB, it works.
I updated 1st post, check it. Can you judge why isValid() always returns false?